# Bigquery Standard SQL - Get Median in last 30 days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table looks like:

document:

```
+-----+-------------+-------------------------+
| dId | score       | datetime                |
+-----+-------------+-------------------------+
| A   | 100.0       | 2019-03-08 16:17:34.043 |
| B   | 80.5        | 2019-02-15 16:17:34.043 |
| C   | 70.1        | 2019-03-08 16:17:34.043 |
+-----+-------------+-------------------------+
```

I want to get Median of score in last 30 days.

My current query is:

```
SELECT
  PERCENTILE_CONT(CASE
      WHEN d.datetime >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 day) THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END) OVER(....) AS Median
FROM
  `document` d
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Median(arr ARRAY<INT64>) AS (
  IF(MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 1, arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))],
      (arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] + arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]) / 2)
);
SELECT Median(ARRAY_AGG(score ORDER BY score)) Median
FROM `project.dataset.document`
WHERE DATE(dt) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

You can tets, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Median(arr ARRAY<INT64>) AS (
  IF(MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 1, arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))],
      (arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] + arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]) / 2)
);
WITH `project.dataset.document` AS (
  SELECT 'A' dId, 100 score, DATETIME '2019-03-08 16:17:34.043' dt UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'B', 80, '2019-02-15 16:17:34.043' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'C', 70, '2019-03-08 16:17:34.043'     
)
SELECT Median(ARRAY_AGG(score ORDER BY score)) Median
FROM `project.dataset.document`
WHERE DATE(dt) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

with result

```
Row Median   
1   85.0
```

Note you can use `CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Median(arr ANY TYPE) AS (...` to make it more generic and accept any type of sequence

> Update

Below example should work for NUMERIC

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Median(arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  IF(MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 1, arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))],
      (arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] + arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]) / 2)
);
WITH `project.dataset.document` AS (
  SELECT 'A' dId, CAST(100.0 AS numeric) score, DATETIME '2019-03-08 16:17:34.043' datetime UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'B', 80.5, '2019-02-15 16:17:34.043' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'C', 70.1, '2019-03-08 16:17:34.043'     
)
SELECT Median(ARRAY_AGG(CAST(score AS FLOAT64) ORDER BY score)) Median
FROM `project.dataset.document`
WHERE DATE(datetime) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

> Update

Ok. Found reason for Internal Error  - it is because of Ordering By Numeric value
So, final version is:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION Median(arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  IF(MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 1, arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))],
      (arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] + arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))]) / 2)
);
WITH `project.dataset.document` AS (
  SELECT 'A' dId, CAST(100.0 AS numeric) score, DATETIME '2019-03-08 16:17:34.043' datetime UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'B', 80.5, '2019-02-15 16:17:34.043' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'C', 70.1, '2019-03-08 16:17:34.043'     
)
SELECT Median(ARRAY_AGG(score ORDER BY CAST(score AS FLOAT64))) Median
FROM `project.dataset.document`
WHERE DATE(datetime) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191322/discussion-on-answer-by-mikhail-berlyant-bigquery-standard-sql-get-median-in-l).

Comment: per @elliott - the fix for the internal error with ORDER BY and NUMERIC should go out in the next couple of weeks; sorry about that. - Thank you, Elliott!

Comment: @user5155835 - you mentioned you have just 13 rows in the table - can you show those values so I can test/troubleshoot with them

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `PERCENTILE_CONT`. Just find `0.5 PERCENTILE_CONT` of all scores filtered by last month using the `WHERE` clause. if you want to get it in one raw use distinct. Here is the query...

```
SELECT
  PERCENTILE_CONT(score, 0.5) OVER() AS Median
FROM
  `document` d
WHERE
   d.datetime >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```

Comment: This gives me Median as 0.0 for each row in the table

Comment: Can you please give me the exact query and data you are used.

Comment: `WITH document AS (
  SELECT 'A' dId, CAST(100.0 AS numeric) score, DATETIME '2019-03-08 16:17:34.043' datetime UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'B', 80.5, '2019-04-15 16:17:34.043' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'C', 70.1, '2019-04-08 16:17:34.043'     
)
SELECT
  PERCENTILE_CONT(score, 0.5) OVER() AS Median
FROM
  document d
WHERE
   d.datetime >= DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 day))`


    when I tried this I got the correct answer in each case (by changing date)

Comment: My query is same as mentioned in the answer

Comment: Do you try my previous comment?